# Creating a button in Excel to Run Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba

Hi Everyone I coded a python script in which i am taking values from Excel sheet and creating a new text file and writing the Excel values into that Text file. So I want to create a excel Button through Macro/VBA(As I have never worked with these two) in which on pressing the Button It run My Python script and give output of the created Text file. I tried with some basic code but it is only Executing and not giving any output. Currently I am running My Python Script in Spider IDE.

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

'Create a shell object
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8\Python 
3.8 (32-bit)"""
PythonScript = """C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\temp.py"""

objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

EDIT: The error I am getting is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNoL.png)

Comment: Does the python script run? If so, that's all you have here. Side note: `Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String` only `PythonScript` is a `String`, `PythonExe` is an implicit `Variant` you need to declare all your variables with their type in VBA.

Comment: Your path to the python.exe is wrong. Your only pointing to the shortcut, the `.exe`should be somewhere along these lines `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `PythonExe` has only a path but no exe file. Also note that you don't need to give the path to the windows start menu but the real path to python which should be something like:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
```

> *Search the real location of your `python.exe` on your computer it might be in another place.*

It should then be something like

```vb
PythonExe = """C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"""
```

and between your `PythonExe` and `PythonScript` needs to be a space:

```vb
objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
```

Finally you need to declare a type for every variable otherwise `PythonExe` is of type `Variant`.

```vb
Dim PythonExe As String, PythonScript As String
```

Comment: I tried As you suggested, but got same error. I have attached the error above in the Question. Please Check

Comment: looks like the path you use for python (in your download folder) is just the setup of python but not the installed one. The path to look for the already installed python must be something like this `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe` You need to install python before using it.

Comment: Yeah I sorted the File location. Now Code is not giving any error but my python script is not running as it is not giving the desired output. while when i am running in my IDE it is working fine.

Comment: run `objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & PythonExe & " " & PythonScript` to see if you get any errors.

Comment: I applied your suggestion. Now command window was opening but directory not found error was showing. then i replaced 3 quotes with 1 quotes while declaring the path of my script and exe file. Now after this seems like script starts running but giving IMPORT MODULE ERROR: openpyxl module not found. But the Package is already installed. I tried to reinstall it through PIP install but showing 'Package is already installed'. But When I am trying to run the script Manually by opening command window it is working.

Comment: @RAJKUMARNAYAK well this is a new error which needs a new question. The old issue of your question (not running the script) is solved.

Comment: In that case, Thanks Mate you really helped me.

Comment: @PEH I noticed when I'm running in VBA, above error is showing like /module import error. But when i am trying to run the script by providing the script path manually in same command window it is giving output with some normal warnings.

Like this is the Error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\script.py", line 8, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

But in same window when i'm giving my script path manually it is working
C:\Users\user\Desktop>Project\script.py

Comment: Looks like there is something in your py script that is wrong and causes some incompatibility. Since we don't know what's in there please open up a new question.

Comment: As an old VBA dog I'm curious why you need a python script to ceate a textfile from Excel data?  I've been creating comma delimited text files for 40 years and VBA has a lot of methods to do that without python.  What am I missing?  I have sevedral different VBA macos for doing that.  If you are interested let me know.

Comment: @JohnMuggins Speed might be a reason to use Python instead of VBA. VBA does not support multi-threadding and can be very slow when it comes to huge amounts of data or calculations that have to be performed programmatically. Nevertheless I haven't tested if there is a benefit in creating a text file. Also running a Python script automatically might be easier than launching a specific VBA macro.