# Run a python script with a button

Tags: python, excel, vba, postgresql

I am trying to create a button that will run a Python script.

I tried with a ipynb not a py file.

I tried the following VBA code:

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String, PythonScriptPath As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExePath = """C:\Users\example"""
PythonScriptPath = """Desktop\1\example.ipynb"""

objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath

End Sub
```

It looks like it's working but it doesn't do anything. It might be I used the wrong code or because the Python code is too complex for this as it's connected to a postressql base and bringing data from there.

How should I automate the Python? Maybe Excel macro button or an executable file?

Answer (score 1):

Your `PythonExePath` variable is not set correctly. It does not point towards your python installation. Locate your python installation, and don't forget to include the executable file in the `PythonExePath` variable.

It currenctly is:

```
PythonExePath = """C:\Users\example"""
```

And should be something like:

```
PythonExePath = """C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"""
```

[Link to duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354918/creating-a-button-in-excel-to-run-python-script)

Comment: Hi, i have done that but still have an error: "Method ''Run'' of object ''IWshShell3" failed. It's basically failing at the last line; objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath. Thanks a lot

Comment: @GeorgianaPislaru Try to add a space between path of exe and script.

Comment: @GeorgianaPislaru replace your last line with `objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & PythonExePath & " " & PythonScriptPath` to see if your shell throws any errors.